# Dynamic URL in Meteor Email Template

Tags: email, meteor, iron-router

I'm  a beginner in Meteor and i would like to send an invitation link to a dynamic generated page in my app with iron:router.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'sendEmail': function(to) {
    this.unblock();

SSR.compileTemplate( 'emailText', Assets.getText( 'html-email.html' ) );

Template.emailText.helpers({
  link:  function () { 
    return Router.current().route.path(this);;
}
});


    Email.send({
      to:to,
      from: 'no-reply@whatever.xyz',
      subject:'xyz wants to invite you ',
      html: SSR.render('emailText')
    });
}})
}
```

The Problem is that i dont get the url of the site in my `html-email.html`. There i got

```
<a href="{{link}}">Link to invitation</a>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is a server method (SSR). `Router.current()` is a client method and cannot return anything server side. The solution is to pass the url as a parameter. Call your method that way :

```
Meteor.call( 'sendEmail', email, url, ... )
```

Then your method will be :

```
'sendEmail': function( to, url ) {...
```

Comment: Good suggestion, although it doesn't answer the question. Question is about getting the link rendered in a email template. See my answer which adds extra parameter to `SSR.render`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I would say you mix up server side methods and client side template helpers.

What do you want to achieve? Want the current route where the user is located in your site to be included in the mail? Then, send the url as an extra parameter in your `sendEmail` method like fabien suggested.
If the link is a static path that you use as a link to some landing page, I suggest to get that path from settings.json.

Either way, your problem is rendering an email with some link in it. You can pass an object as second parameter to `SSR.render`.
Here is how you could solve this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'sendEmail': function(to) {
    this.unblock();

    var linkInMail = 'htpp://some_url/etc?etc'; // Fill this value, see my remark above

    var templateName = 'emailText';
    SSR.compileTemplate(templateName, Assets.getText( 'html-email.html' ) );
    var renderedContent = SSR.render(templateName, {link: linkInMail}); // This your missing part

    Email.send({
      to:to,
      from: 'no-reply@whatever.xyz',
      subject:'xyz wants to invite you ',
      html: renderedContent
    });
}})
}
```

Comment: And then how do you get it in an attribute tag? I pass an object with a lot of info I can render into the email but the specific problem is getting it into an attribute which is what's not working for me. I try `<a href="{{myLink}}"></a>` but it doesn't render the href at all.

Comment: It looks like you are doing it correct. You mention you pass an object. It must contain a myLink field.

Comment: Yea it’s one of those things that just ‘wasn’t working’ but now it is... :)